# Set visibility to GONE, if TextView displays a specific text

Tags: java, android, textview

Is there any way if `TextView` is showing specific text like **0% off** so text  visibility set to gone otherwise its visible.

just like this code

```
if(text.length() == 0 || text.equals(""))
            {
                mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: Depends when and under what condition you want to achieve this.

Comment: Tell us what trigger the text in that `TextView` to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show **1% off** wrap the `TextView` into `CardView` or `LinearLayout` and in recyclerview adapter try this.

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView discountedvalue;

    public CardView cardview;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        discountedvalue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DiscountValue);
        cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        discountedvalue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    if(editable.toString().equals("0 % off")){

                        cardview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }else{

                        cardview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }


                }
            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could implement your logic in a listener, which would fire whenever the user changes the text in the `EditText`.  Have your activity implement `TextWatcher`, then try something like this in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    EditText ed = new EditText(this);
    ed.addTextChangedListener(this);
    setContentView(editText);

    // plus your current code
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String ed_text = ed.getText();
    if (ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("")) {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        mTel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This answer was originally given when the OP was asking about an `EditText`.  Since then, the OP changed the question to a `TextView`, but what I suggest above generally can be used for any listener (e.g. a listener on whatever is updating the `TextView`).

Comment: is it possible with TextView Under recyclerview adapter?

Comment: @user8778752 `TextView`s cannot be edited AFAIK, so the entire premise of your question changes.

Comment: Actually  my question is on TextView.

Answer (score 1):

```
    final TextView text=findViewById(R.id.myTextView);


    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(editable.toString().equals("Your Text ")){

                // 1 - You can set empty text
                text.setText("");
                // 2 - Or you can change the color of the text
                text.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                // 3 - Or you can change the visibility of the view
                text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            }else{

                //Here you should undo your code 

                //1 - if you using method one dose not need to do anything here 
                // for method 2 
                text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                // for method 3
                text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome its work for me. i also thinking to try this method, Anyways thankx.

Answer (score 0):

You can done this using change text color

```
tvPoints.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: But this doesn't say _how_ the OP would actually implement this in his activity.